# Early-binding .NET classes via COM in Excel when isolated

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel, com

In my current project I am trying to write an Excel .NET add-in that hooks into an existing third-party library (via COM/.NET), however, I am a bit of a greenhorn when it comes to COM despite reading quite a bit about it I've never really found a satisfactory solution.

There is an third-party add-in, let's call it `ExcelAddin.xla` that is loaded into Excel which, on startup, creates a new object. It also contains a function to return a property of the `AddinController` object (another class), (below is VBA):

```
Private AddinController as Object

Sub Auto_Open()
    Set AddinController = CreateObject("ExcelAddInController")  
End Sub

Function GetAddinApplication as Object
    Set GetAddinApplication = AddinController.Application
End Function
```

The `ExcelAddInController` is the ProgID of a COM-exposed class in a .NET library (let's call it `ExcelAddInController.dll`) that was also created by the same third party. It appears that the `Application` property is not COM-exposed, however I know the structure of the class.

I am trying to write a .NET-based add-iin for Excel that hooks into `ExcelAddin.xla` and attempts to call `GetAddinApplication` to obtain the `Application` property so that I can do useful things with it.

Initially, I wrote a traditional COM add-in (`MyCOMAddin.dll`) for Excel in VB.NET and referenced the third-party `ExcelAddInController.dll` library so I could get at the classes (below is in VB.NET):

```
<GuidAttribute(Connect.TypeGuid), ProgIdAttribute(Connect.TypeProgId), ComVisible(True)> _
Public Class Connect

    Implements Extensibility.IDTExtensibility2

    Public Const TypeGuid As String = "<guid here>"
    Public Const TypeProgId As String = "MyAddin"

    Private _excelApplication As Excel.Application

    Public Sub OnConnection(ByVal application As Object, ByVal connectMode As Extensibility.ext_ConnectMode, ByVal add-iinInst As Object, ByRef custom As System.Array) Implements Extensibility.IDTExtensibility2.OnConnection
        _excelApplication = TryCast(application, Excel.Application)
        Dim AddinControllerApp as ExcelAddInControllerApplication = TryCast(_excelApplication.Run("ExcelAddin.xla!GetAddinApplication"),ExcelAddInControllerApplication)
    End Sub

End Class
```

This works, and `AddinControllerApp` is populated. However, for best-practice purposes when writing a COM add-in I would like to isolate it (i.e. shim it - I think it's know as putting it in a separate AppDomain? Is that right?) from any other .NET add-ins so that it doesn't cause problems if it crashes (or any other .NET add-ins cause problems either).

I used the Microsoft COMShim tool to create a COM-shim for my add-in, however, when try to use the add-in I received the message:

```
Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to class type 'ExcelAddInControllerApplication'. Instances of types that represent COM components cannot be cast to types that do not represent COM components however they can be cast to interfaces as long as the underlying COM component supports QueryInterface calls for the IID of the interface.
```

I tried a difference approach by using Excel-DNA to "wrap" and results in a registry-free COM add-in, however, I still encounter the same error - so this must be due to either isolation, or something missing.

In this case, is this solvable so that I can use early-binding in my add-in, or do I need to use late-binding to interact with the third-party library? It's not a huge issue either way, I just wanted to be sure there wasn't some clever trick I could use to use early-binding (for code auto-complete etc.).

Comment: What is today? the VB.NET and VBA are similar awareness day? Choose: VB.NET or VBA. Well... I have to recognise that out of all the supporters of the VB.NET-VBA mix-up I have seen today (many more than usual, that's why my aforementioned question), you are the one with the most solid reasons... but in which language you have the error/doubt/problem?

Comment: Thank you, good point... It involves both, but I think probably VB.NET is the primary concern so I updated the tags.

Comment: This is certainly a dense question which seems easily summarisable/cleareadable: you have a VB.NET code connecting via COM to an Excel macro; it works, but you are asking about the best coding proceeding to build a safe and reliable code. Also you have tried some libraries (you are just mentioning). I am not experienced enough to help you on this, but here come my advices to get help quicker:

Comment: Just remove all the text above the VB.NET code. And below it, intend to summarise the ideas (= "it works, but can I do it better?") and highlight the libraries you tried + the errors. You can convert a dense, 20-lines-of-explanations question into a clear 5-lines one, with much higher chances of getting a quick answer. But this is just my opinion...